# How to i parse this json?

Tags: android, json

```
    String jsondata="{\"studentResult\":[{\"sem1\" :[{\"subname\":\"TOC\",\"subcode\":\"1009\",\"subcredit\":\"6\",\"subgrade\":\"AB\"},
    {\"subname\":\"DS\",\"subcode\":\"10090\",\"subcredit\":\"5\",\"subgrade\":\"BB\"},
    {\"subname\":\"TOC\",\"subcode\":\"1009\",\"subcredit\":\"6\",\"subgrade\":\"AB\"}]},{\"sem2\":
   [{\"subname\":\"AAS\",\"subcode\":\"111009\",\"subcredit\":\"6\",\"subgrade\":\"AB\"},
{\"subname\":\"AE\",\"subcode\":\"103309\",\"subcredit\":\"6\",\"subgrade\":\"DD\"}] }]}";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this here:

```
String json = "{\"key\":\"value\",\"key\":\"value\"}";

try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    Log.i("My App", "JSONObject in String: " + obj.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON - JSON strings cannot be single quoted, they must be double quoted. http://www.json.org/

Comment: Thanks Adam - fixxed!